# .net 4 - run code from string - in C# / F# / IronRuby / IronPython

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.0, eval, ironruby

What ways do I have in .net to run code from string?

```
Console.WriteLine(Compile("1 + 2 * 3"));    // results is 7.
```

What other options do we have?

- C# - Compile the code on runtime?
- IronRuby / IronPython?
- F#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the dynamic languages like IronRuby and IronPython make it very easy to do what you want.  Create a script engine and execute the string.  Easy as that.

C#, it is possible, using the Code DOM... but it it compiles the code every time into a DLL.  This is a costly behavior and can cause your app to grow in memory size over time if you don't do some tricky stuff with App Domains.  It CAN be done, but I really prefer using IronRuby or IronPython over this approach.  It is much more simple.

Finally, in C# 5.0, we are expecting to see the compiler as a managed service.  This means you will be able to run eval("//c#code") in the future... but it is not available yet.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You say it's very easy to create an `Eval` function using IronPython.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout NCalc.  It's a dll you can include in your application and it supports multiple math and logic operations. http://ncalc.codeplex.com/