# C# - can I define a function on the fly from a user-supplied string formula?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, mathematical-expressions

I can define a func with a lambda expression as in:

```
Func <int, int, int> Fxy = ( (a,b) => a + b ) );  // Fxy does addition
```

But what if I wanted to allow the user to supply the r.h.s. of the lambda expression at runtime ?

```
String formula_rhs = Console.Readline();
// user enters "a - b"
```

Can I somehow modify Fxy as if I had coded

```
Func <int, int, int> Fxy = ( (a,b) => a - b ) );  // Fxy does what the user wants 
                                                  // (subtraction)
```

I presently use a home built expression parser to accept user-defined formulas.  Just starting up w .NET, and I get the feeling there may be a not-too-painful way to do this.

Comment: Have you seen Dynamic LINQ? http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965597/net-4-run-code-from-string-in-c-f-ironruby-ironpython

Answer (score 1):

Try the ncalc framework: http://ncalc.codeplex.com/
Its easy and lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

Is not so easy. [This library](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx) contains some Dynamic Linq features you can use to convert a lambda expression from text to Func<>, have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

System.Reflection.Emit namespace is intended for code generation on-the-fly. It is quite complicated in general but may help for simple functions like subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use not complex formulas, JScript engine would easy solution:

```
        Microsoft.JScript.Vsa.VsaEngine engine = Microsoft.JScript.Vsa.VsaEngine.CreateEngine();
        MessageBox.Show(Microsoft.JScript.Eval.JScriptEvaluate("((2+3)*5)/2", engine).ToString());
```

Dont forget to add reference to `Microsoft.JScript` assembly

Answer (score 0):

Using [Linq.Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx) could be an idea here.

Your example would tranlate to:

```
var a = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "a");
var b = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "b");
var sum = Expression.Subtract(a, b);
var lamb = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int, int>>(sum, a, b);
Func<int, int, int> Fxy = lamb.Compile();
```

Ofcourse, you will have the fun of parsing a string into the correct expressions. :-)